# Most pythonic way to reuse a generator?

Tags: python, generator

I have two generators with the following signature:

- `gen1(inputs) -> Iterator[A]`
- `gen2(Iterator[A]) -> Iterator[B]`

My goal is to write another generator (let's called it `final_gen`) that gives me both `A` and `B`.

However, if I chain `gen1` and `gen2` together, like

```py
def final_gen(inputs):
    yield from gen2(gen1(inputs))
```

`gen1` would be consumed and I can't get `A` back.

Just wondering what is the pythonic way to "reuse" `gen1`?

**Update**
I can think of a few ways, but I'm not satisfied with any

1. Collect `gen1` into a tuple or list, so that I can use those values. This is memory-inefficient.
2. Use `itertools.tee` to create a clone of `gen1`. However this is computation-inefficient.

Comment: I sympathize with your desire to find another way, but I think you've successfully listed out the only two ways to do this. Either consume the iterator into an iterable (most prominently `list` or `tuple`), or `tee` it into two separate generators.

Comment: Does `gen2` do any tabulation/accumlation/is idempotent?  You could pass them into gen2 one at time:  `(gen2(item) for item in gen1(inputs))`.  Why are they generators? vs functions?

Comment: I guess I can do this: `((next(gen2([item])), item) for item in gen1(inputs))`. I need to wrap `item` into a list before passing to `gen2` and call `next` on it, just to follow the signature of `gen2`.

Comment: @JohnMee They are generators because the list of items is long, and I want to take advantage of laziness.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking a combination of [`itertools.tee()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.tee) to duplicate your input and then wrapping it into another function that returns the result of the two generator chains.

Something along the lines of this, (as found in [itertools' recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools-recipes))

```py
def partition(pred, iterable):
    "Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries"
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)
```